# Split a Texture into puzzle pieces In libgdx

Tags: java, android, bitmap, opengl-es, libgdx

I am trying to convert android Canvas based game to Libgdx due to performance issues. Currently I am facing issues when I have to generate jigsaw puzzle piece sprites (dynamically).

**What I did :** I used android bitmap manipulation (Path and PorterDuff) and generated puzzle pieces and then fed that to Libgdx Game object in AndroidLauncher.

**Question 1** : Is there a better way to convert a bitmap to puzzle pieces inside libgdx core project. (see below)

[image]

**Question 2** : How can I create an area just to represent the puzzle piece.
(bounding box or width/height based solution is not suitable), so that user can drag the piece when he/she only touches on that texture area.

**Question 3** : Best way to detect when adjacent puzzle pieces are moved closer to each other by the user.

Comment: I think this would be pretty hard to achieve through code. Couldn't you just draw each puzzle piece and create a function which draws each puzzle piece and makes the big image disappear?

Comment: And you may want to see using box 2d and rube editor for touch detection and collisions. (if you want them to be precise)

Comment: You could use alpha masks.

Comment: Thanks for response. Can you please give me bit more info. Also how to tackle Question 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

Best Way to create a jigsaw puzzle game in LibGdx. There is an alternative to achieve pieces from an Image in LibGdx by using masking. Masking is achieved by creating a Shader Program i.e for this problem we have to write a 
1.Vertex Shader 
2.Fragment Shader
3.Create A Shader Program
4.create a custom sprite batch.
for more info on shaders: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Shaders

Shader Program looks like this:
Below Vertex Shader For masking:-

1. Vertex Shader: Vertex shaders are responsible for performing operations on vertices.

   ` 
       uniform mat4 u_projTrans;

   ```
   attribute vec4 a_position;

   attribute vec4 a_color;

   attribute vec2 a_texCoord0;

   varying vec4 v_color;
   varying vec2 v_texCoord0;

   void main()
   {
       v_color = a_color;
       v_texCoord0 = a_texCoord0;
       gl_Position = u_projTrans * a_position;
   } `
   ```

2.Fragment Shader: A fragment shader functions in a very similar way to a vertex shader. But instead of processing it on a vertex it processes it once for each fragment.

```
`#ifdef GL_ES
    precision mediump float;
#endif

uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform sampler2D u_mask;

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoord0;

void main()
{
    vec4 texColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoord0);
    vec4 mask = texture2D(u_mask, v_texCoord0);
    texColor.a *= mask.a;
    gl_FragColor = v_color * texColor;
}`
```

3. create a Shader Program using Vertex and fragment Shader:

   ```
   public class MyShader {
   private FileHandle fragmentShader = Gdx.files.internal("fragment.glsl");
   private FileHandle vertexShader = Gdx.files.internal("vertex.glsl");
   public ShaderProgram myShader = new ShaderProgram(this.vertexShader, 
   this.fragmentShader);

   public MyShader () {
       this.myShader .begin();
       this.myShader .setUniformi("u_texture", 0);
       this.myShader .setUniformi("u_mask", 1);
       this.myShader .end();
   }
   ```

   }

4.Custom Sprite Batch for Masking:

```
    batch.setShader(MyShader.myShader);
    this.alphaTexture.bind(1);
    this.color.getTexture().bind(0);
    batch.enableBlending();
    Color c = getColor();
    batch.draw(this.color, getX(), getY(), getOriginX(), 
    getOriginY(), 
    getWidth(), getHeight(), getScaleX(), getScaleY(), 0.0f);
    batch.setShader(null);
```

ShaderLesson: https://github.com/mattdesl/lwjgl-basics/wiki/ShaderLesson2

Comment: Also Have a look at: < https://github.com/mattdesl/lwjgl-basics/wiki/Custom-Sprite-Batcher-in-LibGDX>