# Overlap detection on part of sprite in Libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx, collision-detection, polygon, overlap

I have image sprites representing two polygons below. These polygons loosely represent the sprite area. What I want to do is use these polygons to detect the overlap (or collision) of sprites. However the overlap should be valid inside the green square. (this is a jigsaw puzzle game, what I am trying to implement is snapping of puzzle pieces when they are moved closer)

I tried `Intersector.overlapConvexPolygons(adjacentPiece.polygon, currentPiece.polygon);` however this one detects overlaps for entire polygon.

Any clever things I can do here to detect the overlap.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You may want to just use box 2d for collisions.

Answer (score 1):

I think your approach might be over-complicating it. If you need your puzzle pieces to bump into each other, you can keep your physics boundaries, but if not, you can remove them entirely.

Either way, to detect if two pieces should snap, you can approximate each piece by a point roughly at the center of each of the piece's four basic sides. To test for pieces being close enough to snap together, you only need to measure the distance between the points on the sides of the two pieces and see if it's smaller than some threshold value you want to use.

If this is a typical puzzle game, you would only need to check this when the player releases a piece, so if it takes a while to brute-force cycle through all the potential matches, it won't really be noticeable because it isn't done while the player is dragging pieces.

Comment: Thanks for that. Please see the new illustration. Is this what you mean?
Based on this image we measure Y distance and compare that with a threshold. What about X?

Comment: Not exactly. I mean that you have four points for each puzzle piece, one at the middle of each of the four sides. Not a single point at the center of the whole piece.

Comment: Thanks I ll try it out. BTW I created polygons to create touch area for puzzle pieces. Do you know a better approach for this. Here is the question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46292589/limit-touch-area-to-texture-area-in-libgdx/46293793#46293793

Comment: I don't know how difficult your method is...if it's working I'd leave it alone unless it's causing you performance problems or costing you too much time to set up. A more automated approach might be when the screen is touched, draw your game pieces to a FrameBuffer, but with solid colors (a unique color for each piece). This would require a specialized shader. You could use GL scissoring to avoid drawing more than you need for performance. Then check the color the pixel in the corresponding touch location on the FrameBuffer.

Answer (score 1):

If all your jigsaw pieces are a regular size you can simple use normal squares for each jigsaw piece. The square used to define the shape will be halfway between the solid part of the jigsaw piece and the extruded pieces.

From your image I have applied the squares to the pieces shown.

[image]

Comment: Thanks , I am continuing on this path. BTW do you know a way to create puzzle piece sprites from a full square picture. Currently I create puzzle piece images dynamically from android methods and load them to libgdx. There are problems in translation . Full question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46271718/split-a-texture-into-puzzle-pieces-in-libgdx?noredirect=1#comment79521703_46271718